# Docker Engine API connect to an existing network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network, docker-engine

I have to connect a container created with Docker Engine API to an existing network.

```
$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                      DRIVER              SCOPE
2babcf993368        bridge                    bridge              local
8a865b5fedae        cron-container_my-net     bridge              local
94e1d6468f07        host                      host                local
92f72e792ec8        none                      null                local
```

The network i want to my container must connect is *cron-container_my-net* and this is my .json for the container creating.

```
{
    "Image": "my-job",
    "Name": "my-container",
    "HostConfig": {
        "NetworkMode": "cron-container_my-net"
    },
    "NetworkDisable": "false"
}
```

In this way if i do an inspect:

```
$ docker inspect my-container
[...]
"NetworkSettings": {
    "Bridge": "",
    "SandboxID": "130b79dca9cf45fed41e50da897e8d37a18160900a8390733300dc01f691ac94",
    "HairpinMode": false,
    "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
    "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "Ports": {},
    "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/130b79dca9cf",
    "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
    "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
    "EndpointID": "",
    "Gateway": "",
    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "IPAddress": "",
    "IPPrefixLen": 0,
    "IPv6Gateway": "",
    "MacAddress": "",
    "Networks": {
        "cron-container_my-net": {
            "IPAMConfig": null,
            "Links": null,
            "Aliases": [
                "387929d92ffc"
            ],
            "NetworkID": "8a865b5fedaea1192ec0c6dcd742fc51af28001132c0ae375bdca018eb4706c9",
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "MacAddress": "",
            "DriverOpts": null
        }
    }
}
```

But if i do an inspect to a container already connected to the network this is the result:

```
$ docker inspect other-container
[...]
"NetworkSettings": {
    "Bridge": "",
    "SandboxID": "0d5e7e600a3ef46090675409a5eb444c1e31520e3c8c6908e6bda69ba9759335",
    "HairpinMode": false,
    "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
    "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "Ports": {
        "3000/tcp": null
    },
    "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/0d5e7e600a3e",
    "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
    "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
    "EndpointID": "",
    "Gateway": "",
    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "IPAddress": "",
    "IPPrefixLen": 0,
    "IPv6Gateway": "",
    "MacAddress": "",
    "Networks": {
        "cron-container_my-net": {
            "IPAMConfig": null,
            "Links": null,
            "Aliases": [
                "89c1aa28e3af",
                "socket-io"
            ],
            "NetworkID": "8a865b5fedaea1192ec0c6dcd742fc51af28001132c0ae375bdca018eb4706c9",
            "EndpointID": "01f46a675125c2978de706a2c2ae46f942546028309e18c5561c91f3e7b147e4",
            "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
            "IPAddress": "172.18.0.3",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
            "DriverOpts": null
        }
    }
}
```

How can connect my-container?